# QT segmentation fault when using BCM2835 for SPI

Tags: pi-3, spi, qt

I am a novice when it comes to programming. I am attempting to set up SPI communication between a module and my RPI3.

The following is my main.cpp code (I plan to neaten up the code once it works)

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "bcm2835.h"

#define PIN18 RPI_GPIO_18
#define PIN16 RPI_GPIO_16
#define WORD_SIZE 4U

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  if (!bcm2835_init()) {
              qDebug() << ("Could not init bcm2835") << endl;
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

  bcm2835_gpio_fsel(PIN18, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);
  bcm2835_gpio_write(PIN18, LOW);
  delay(100);
  bcm2835_gpio_write(PIN18, HIGH);
  delay(100);
  bcm2835_spi_begin();
  bcm2835_spi_setBitOrder(BCM2835_SPI_BIT_ORDER_MSBFIRST);
  bcm2835_spi_setDataMode(BCM2835_SPI_MODE0);
  bcm2835_spi_setClockDivider(BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_512);
  bcm2835_spi_chipSelect(BCM2835_SPI_CS0);
  bcm2835_spi_setChipSelectPolarity(BCM2835_SPI_CS0, LOW);
  bcm2835_gpio_fsel(PIN16, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_INPT);

  w.show();

  return a.exec();
}
```

I get an segmentation fault at

bcm2835_spi_setDataMode (main.cpp) --->

bcm2835_peri_set_bits (bcm2835.c)  --->

bcm2835_peri_read (bcm2835.c) --->

ret = *paddr (bcm2835.c)

I have reason to believe the pointer is attempting to access an address at "paddr" that I do not have permission to or that doesn't exist.

Please help,
thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of the bcm2835 library are you using?

Comment: The library version is bcm2835-1.50

Comment: I tested the code on Geany and it worked but since trying to create a GUI on Qt I have had problems

Comment: PIN16 isn't defined in your code.  I presume that's a typo.  I'd ask on the bcm2835 forum as it works in Geany but not Qt.

Comment: Yes sorry it was a typo

Comment: Have you enabled the SPI interface in the [device tree](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-pi-spi-and-i2c-tutorial) ?
In short, the steps are `sudo raspi-config -> advanced options -> SPI -> enable SPI : (yes) -> automatically load kernel module : (yes) -> Finish -> reboot`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I discovered that was my fault, I mean you have to check the return value of a function and manage it in case of error.

In this case the function bcm2835_spi_begin(); returns operation status, as you can see in the documentation:

> Start SPI operations. Forces RPi SPI0 pins P1-19 (MOSI), P1-21 (MISO),
>   P1-23 (CLK), P1-24 (CE0) and P1-26 (CE1) to alternate function ALT0,
>   which enables those pins for SPI interface. You should call
>   bcm2835_spi_end() when all SPI funcitons are complete to return the
>   pins to their default functions.
>
> See also bcm2835_spi_end() Returns 1 if successful, 0 otherwise
>   (perhaps because you are not running as root)

The most important thing of this explanation, is the last sentence where it says that **you must  run your appplication as root user**. Otherwise bcm2835_spi_begin() will return you 0. As you do not check it, you have this segmentation fault error.

I hope it helps.

Regards.